# How to add component presentations to a page during creation using Core Service in Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

I am creating a page through the core service.
I want to add component presentations to it.

I have created the page like this:

```
var page = new Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.PageData
{
    Title = "pagecore",
    FileName = "pagecore",
    Id = "tcm:0-0-0",
    LocationInfo = new LocationInfo
    {
        OrganizationalItem = new LinkToOrganizationalItemData { IdRef = "tcm:9-44-4" }
    },
    IsPageTemplateInherited= false,
    PageTemplate=new LinkToPageTemplateData { IdRef = "tcm:9-545-128" }, 
}
```

I am unable to add component presentations to it.

Can any one tell me how to add the component presentations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set collection of `ComponentPresentationData` objects to `ComponentPresentations` property of `PageData`, like this:

```
ComponentPresentations = new[]
{
   new ComponentPresentationData
   {
       Component = new LinkToComponentData{ IdRef = "tcm:9-16"},
       ComponentTemplate = new LinkToComponentTemplateData{ IdRef = "tcm:9-20-32"}
   }, 
}
```